# Counting all the occurrences of a substing in a string using regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I've seen many examples of this but didn't helped. I have the following string:

```
var str = 'asfasdfasda'
```

and I want to extract the following

```
asfa asfasdfa asdfa asdfasda asda
```

i.e all sub-strings starting with 'a' and ending with 'a'

here is my regular expression

```
/a+[a-z]*a+/g
```

but this always returns me only one match:

```
[ 'asdfasdfsdfa' ]
```

Someone can point out mistake in my implementation.

Thanks.

**Edit** Corrected no of substrings needed. Please note that overlapping and duplicate substring are required as well.

Answer (score 5):

For capturing overlapping matches you will need to lookahead regex and grab the captured group #1 and #2:

```
/(?=(a.*?a))(?=(a.*a))/gi
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mZ7dY8/4)

**Explanation:**

`(?=...)` is called a lookahead which is a zero-width assertion like anchors or word boundary. It just looks ahead but doesn't move the regex pointer ahead thus giving us the ability to grab overlapping matches in groups.

[See more on look arounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

---

**Code:**

```
var re = /(?=(a.*?a))(?=(a.*a))/gi;
var str = 'asfasdfasda';
var m; 
var result = {};
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex)
        re.lastIndex++;
    result[m[1]]=1;
    result[m[2]]=1;
}

console.log(Object.keys(result));
//=> ["asfa", "asfasdfasda", "asdfa", "asdfasda", "asda"]
```

Comment: I didnt know about this. how to capture matched string, count is correct but getting matchec strings ""

Comment: OP wants overlapping matches and that are available in the index 1 of matched array.

Comment: Tried this. var str = 'asfasdfasda';
str.match(/(?=(a[^a]*a))/gi);
 getting ["", "", ""].. can you write a snippet to show

Comment: I'm very sorry for this, but I somehow added wrong number of substring I need. I'll update my question in a min.

Answer (score 1):

parser doesnt goto previous state on tape to match the start a again.

```js
var str = 'asfaasdfaasda'; // you need to have extra 'a' to mark the start of next string

var substrs = str.match(/a[b-z]*a/g); // notice the regular expression is changed.

alert(substrs)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can count it this way:

```
var str = "asfasdfasda";
var regex = /a+[a-z]*a+/g, result, indices = [];
while ((result = regex.exec(str))) {
     console.log(result.index); // you can instead count the values here.
}
```